# Angular Build Issue - Error in type is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, production-environment, angularbuild

I am facing strange issue while building angular project. I do not know why its happening.

Following is the error

"ERROR in type is not defined
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
16% building modules 3/5 modules 2 active …rackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\src\styles.scssD:\Working Projects\TrackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:480
throw e;
^

ReferenceError: type is not defined
at syntaxError (D:\Working Projects\TrackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:530:29)
at validateAnalyzedModules (D:\Working Projects\TrackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31268:15)    at mergeAndValidateNgFiles (D:\Working Projects\TrackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31458:12)    at AotCompiler.loadFilesSync (D:\Working Projects\TrackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:30666:16)
at AngularCompilerProgram.initSync (D:\Working Projects\TrackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:384:49)
at AngularCompilerProgram.get [as tsProgram] (D:\Working Projects\TrackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:359:22)
at AngularCompilerProgram.getTsSyntacticDiagnostics (D:\Working Projects\TrackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:109:21)
at checkDiagnostics (D:\Working Projects\TrackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\gather_diagnostics.js:38:27)
at Object.gatherDiagnostics (D:\Working Projects\TrackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\gather_diagnostics.js:60:9)
at TypeChecker._diagnose (D:\Working Projects\TrackQlik\ERPISTO.Web.UI\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\type_checker.js:94:53)"

Can someone please help me in it? I am struck here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are facing an exception: `ReferenceError`: type is not defined. This is because the reference for the some variable does not exist in either local or global scope and may be you are still trying to use it. A `ReferenceError` exception is thrown when a non-existent variable is accessed.